# Detect running rsync session

Tags: rsync

I have a remote system, over which I don't have any control, uploading a lot of files over rsync/ssh from time to time. After that I need to process the files. But I can't touch incomplete copy. How do I detect if there's an rsync session ongoing and bail out?

Answer (score 1):

You can check with lsof before copying the file to see if some program has it open, example:

[root@pr467958 ~]# lsof /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
mysqld  23262 mysql   12u  unix 0xffff880fd8573600      0t0 15647622 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqld  23262 mysql   13u  unix 0xffff8800260bc900      0t0 18648027 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

The output of lsof will be blank if no program has the file open so the problem is a quite simple scripting matter: if the output is blank copy the file if not leave it by now

```
lsofoutput=`lsof /home/myfile`
if [ ! $lsofoutput ]
then
   cp /home/myfile /somewhere/else
fi
```

Just one last thing. If you don't have control over that system but you have a ssh user/password then you do have control, just issue the above commands over ssh like this:

```
ssh root@8.8.8.8 exec "/root/scripts/the-above-script.sh"
```

Comment: I have tens of thousands files. Do you mean that I need to check every other file?

Comment: Of course that has to be done automatically. 

- You get the list of files by using ls or find and put it inside an array.
- Loop the array and for every file location run the above code inside the loop.
- If the output of lsof is null then you can copy the file, if not you leave it and continue with the next file.

Comment: For the amount of files I have this approach will take more time than the actual sync.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to that machine you should try

> ps auxc | grep rsync

It'll show you running rsync processes.